# Is there a way to query Azure security recommendations (ASC) in Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-security

Wanting to find if there is a way to query azure security recommendations in log analytics

I checked if the schema "SecurityEvent" has details related to this. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As Azure Security Center search and other related features are getting retired as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-features-retirement-july2019) so AFAIK [Azure Sentinel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/) would be the right one to leverage now which enables us to query and also connect alerts from Azure Security Center and stream them into it. For more information, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/connect-azure-security-center) document. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey if i understand your question properly. You need to understand if you can get the recommendation which the Azure Security Center provides through Log Analytics Kusto queries. ? If so then

You should be able to query once you have linked the Azure Security Center in your subscription to your log analytics instance workspace.

For linking your need to go to Azure Portal ->Azure Security Center -> Pricing and settings -> Select the subscription and workspace (Follow the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-enable-data-collection )

once this is linked successful you should see the below schema 'security' or 'securityfree' based on what you have chosen. Like in the screen shot below.

[image]